# Error when deploying custom template in Azure from Azure DevOps repo ("deploy to azure" button)

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

All,

I'm trying to use the "deploy to Azure" button, using a template stored in Azure DevOps Git repo.
I'm receiving the following error:
`Error parsing template. Please ensure template is valid JSON. Invalid symbol at character position 4. (3 other errors)`.

I created the URL following what is described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-azure-button.

My structure is the following:

- Azure DevOps organization = `MyOrganization` and project is `myProject`
- Repo is `myRepo`, and the template file is on branch `myBranch`, located at `myFolder/myTemplate.json`.

At the end, the URL looks like
[https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2F{myOrganization}%2F{myProject}%2F_apis%2Fgit%2Frepositories%2F{myRepo}%2Fitems%3Fpath%3D%2F{myFolder}%2F{myTemplate}.json%26versionDescriptor.version%3D{myBranch}%26versionDescriptor.versionType%3Dbranch%26api-version%3D6.0](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2F%7BmyOrganization%7D%2F%7BmyProject%7D%2F_apis%2Fgit%2Frepositories%2F%7BmyRepo%7D%2Fitems%3Fpath%3D%2F%7BmyFolder%7D%2F%7BmyTemplate%7D.json%26versionDescriptor.version%3D%7BmyBranch%7D%26versionDescriptor.versionType%3Dbranch%26api-version%3D6.0)

Copy/pasting this URL in a browser returns the above error...

I believe my JSON file is correct (no error) because it works fine in the following two situations:

- if using the same JSON template file with Azure CLI (`az deployment groupe create --template-file <myJSONtemplatefile> --parameters <myJSONparametersfile>`
- if copy/pasting the JSON template file in Azure portal for custom deployment at https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template

I don't get what is the reason of the `Error parsing template...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!
Issue was due to the fact that the AzDO repo is private, and not public.
This was clearly stated in Microsoft documentation, but I missed it... (bolding word is mine)

> If you're using [Git with Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/) instead of a GitHub repo, you can still use the Deploy to Azure button. Make sure your repo is **public**. Use the [Items operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get) to get the template.

With a public AzDO repo, everything works like a charm.